# How many strings of 8 digits end with an even digit?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So there are $10$ combinations for each digit except the last which has 5 possibilities ($0,2,4,6,8$). Thus $10*10*10*10*10*10*10*5=50000000$ combinations right?

As a follow up, how many strings of 8 digits have at least one repeated digit?

I'm not sure how to approach this one. The first digit you have $10$ possibilities and then the next digit you only have $1$ possibility and for the next $6$ digits you have $10$ possibilities  for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on the # of combinations with an even digit.

For the case of strings with 8 digits with at least one repeated digit, try counting the total number of strings with 8 digits ($10^8$) and subtracting the number of strings with no repeated digits ($10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3$ where the number goes down by 1 for each place since you can't repeat any of the digits to the left of the digit you're placing, if you build the numbers left to right).

Comment: The first term should be 9 and not $10$- can't start a number with $0$

Comment: @voldemort it depends on whether we're talking about 8 digit numbers or strings of digits of length 8. It sounded like the OP wanted strings of digits of length 8, so starting with a zero is no problem.

Comment: @user2566092: ok- if the latter then I retract my comment. Sorry Batman :).

Comment: @Batman so it would be $10^8-(10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3)=98185600$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question your reasing is almost correct, except that for the first place you have $9$ choices and not $10$ as an $8$ digit number can't begin with $0$.

For the follow up question, find the number of $8$ digit numbers with no repeated digits. (i.e. look at the complement).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to answer your first question using basic logic:

To start with, how many 8 digit numbers are there?

Eight digit numbers start at 10,000,000 and proceed to 99,999,999. That gives us a total of 90,000,000 possible numbers. Half of those numbers end with an even digit.

90,000,000 * 1/2 = 45,000,000.

**So, that answer must be 45,000,000.**

If instead, you want strings of eight digits, you can now include 00000000 through 99999999 which give us 100,000,000 possible strings.

Still, half of those strings end with an even digit. **That answer is 50,000,000.**